# IIS 7.5 401 only from Windows Service

Tags: authentication, iis, http-status-code-401

I have a simple webservice running on IIS 7.5. When accessing the webservice from an external PC everything works fine. When my windows service tries to access the webservice the service gets a 401 - unauthorized error message. The windows service is running under the local system account and on the same server as the IIS. The site is using Anonymous authentication with no other types of authentication enabled.

I tried a few other pages related to the 401 error and they did not solve the issues. I tried to give windows file system access to IUSR (along with the IIS_IUSRS). The application pool is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity.

My assumption is that the issue is not IIS since it works fine from an external PC so is there a way to block the local system account from IIS access?

Any other suggestions based on the information I provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help in your web.config:

```
<location path="YourFolder/YourFile.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```